# Assigning data to a given element in a vector within a rule

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to set up a parser which, given a value, can assign it to a certain element of a vector, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it.

Let's say the following piece of code parses the string `(0){**+*+}`. It should increment `bar.a[0]` once for every `+`, and `bar.b[0]` once for every `*`. The issue I'm encountering is that I'm not sure how to get a reference to a vector's element using `_a`:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <vector>

//The struct containing the vector.
struct testStruct {
    std::vector<int> a, b;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT (
    testStruct,
    (std::vector<int>, a)
    (std::vector<int>, b)
)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template<typename Iterator>
struct foo : qi::grammar<Iterator, testStruct(), qi::locals<unsigned>, ascii::space_type> {
    foo() : foo::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi::labels;
        using qi::eps;
        using qi::lit;
        using qi::uint_;
        using phoenix::at_c;

        start = lit('(')
                >> uint_                [_a = _1]
                >> ')'
                >> '{'
                >>  starsOrPlus(
                        at_c<_a>(at_c<0>(_val)),    //This is where I'm not sure what to do.
                        at_c<_a>(at_c<1>(_val))
                    )
                >> '}'
                ;

        starsOrPlus = eps               [_r1 = 0]
                                        [_r2 = 0]
            >> (
                * (
                    (
                        +lit('+')       [_r1 += 1]
                    )
                    ^ (
                        +lit('*')       [_r2 += 1]
                    )
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, testStruct(), qi::locals<unsigned>, ascii::space_type> start;

    //Parses stars and pluses. Sets the first uint8_t to the number of *, and the
    //second to the number of +.
    qi::rule<Iterator, void(int&, int&), ascii::space_type> starsOrPlus;
};

//Main program
int main() {
    std::string testString = "(2){**++*+}";

    typedef foo<std::string::const_iterator> foo;
    foo grammar;

    testStruct bar;
    std::string::const_iterator iter = testString.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = testString.end();
    bool parsed = phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, ascii::space, bar);

    if (parsed) {
        //Do something with the data...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile with the following errors:

```
main.cpp||In constructor 'foo<Iterator>::foo()':|
main.cpp|36|error: 'boost::spirit::_a' cannot appear in a constant-expression|
main.cpp|36|error: no matching function for call to 'at_c(boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::at_eval<0>, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > >&)'|
main.cpp|37|error: 'boost::spirit::_a' cannot appear in a constant-expression|
main.cpp|37|error: no matching function for call to 'at_c(boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::at_eval<1>, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > >&)'|
```

So, clearly, I can't use a placeholder value within `at_c`. I'm also aware that, even if I could, there would also be the issue of re-sizing the vector if the given position is out of range.

How would I implement something like this? Am I just going about this entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>

struct testStruct
{
    std::vector<int> a, b;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
    testStruct,
    (std::vector<int>, a)
    (std::vector<int>, b)
)

namespace bp = boost::phoenix;
namespace bs = boost::spirit;
namespace bsq = bs::qi;

template<typename Iterator>
struct foo : bsq::grammar<Iterator, testStruct(), bsq::locals<unsigned> >
{
    foo() : foo::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace bs::labels;
        using bp::at_c;
        using bp::resize;
        using bs::lit;
        using bs::uint_;

        start
            =   '('
                >> uint_
                   [
                       _a = _1,
                       resize(at_c<0>(_val), _1 + 1),
                       resize(at_c<1>(_val), _1 + 1)
                   ]
                >> "){"
                >> starsOrPlus(at_c<0>(_val)[_a], at_c<1>(_val)[_a])
                >> '}'
            ;

        starsOrPlus
            =  *(
                    lit('+')[_r1 += 1]
                |   lit('*')[_r2 += 1]
                )
            ;
    }

    bsq::rule<Iterator, testStruct(), bsq::locals<unsigned> > start;
    bsq::rule<Iterator, void(int&, int&)> starsOrPlus;
};

void printvec(std::vector<int> const& vec)
{
    bool first = true;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(), it_end = vec.end();
         it != it_end;
         ++it)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << *it;
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo<std::string::const_iterator> grammar;
    testStruct bar;
    std::string const input = "(2){**++*}";
    std::string::const_iterator first = input.begin(), last = input.end();
    if (bsq::parse(first, last, grammar, bar) && first == last)
    {
        std::cout << "bar.a: ";
        printvec(bar.a);
        std::cout << "\nbar.b: ";
        printvec(bar.b);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    else
        std::cout << "parse failed\n";
}
```

The notable changes here are:

- The `vector`s inside of `testStruct` must be resized to a size sufficient for the desired index to be valid
- `operator[]` is used instead of `boost::phoenix::at_c` to access the index of a `vector`, just as one would in "normal" code

Note that I took out the skip parser to simplify things (and because it didn't appear to be necessary); add it back if you need to -- it had no real relevance here.

Comment: Thanks very much! I don't know why I hadn't considered doing it that way. Also, that's certainly a better way of doing starsOrPlus, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is it necessary to pass testStruct() to grammar. Can't I have use it inside the grammar without passing it explicitly? Let's say that your start rule does not have testStruct as a attribute but some other rule has, then?

Comment: @Dilawar : `testStruct` only needs to be passed in to `parse` if the caller of `parse` wants it as a "return value". I.e., if `testStruct` is only used internally in the grammar and can be discarded when parsing is complete, then no, it is not necessary to pass it in to `parse`.